# Touchscreen re-enables itself after waking up on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, touchscreen, xinput

I have added a startup command on the startup applications program to disable my touchscreen on every startup since it occasionally has issues that seriously mess up the input:

`xinput disable "ELAN Touchscreen"` (I do not use device IDs since they change after every reboot).

However, after a few wake ups, the touchscreen turns on again. Is there anyway to stop this issue?

Comment: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tutorial-how-to-disable-a-touchscreen-device/5100

Comment: @tso seems to be working well so far. I will let you know if there is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit file the file with

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

Change MatchIsTouchscreen from "on" to "off" so it looks like this

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
  MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver "evdev"
  EndSection
```

Save, Name and Exit nano

"ELAN touchscreen" is disabled and no longer detected in xinput list.

Answer (score 0):

When your system "wakes up" (Recovers from  Suspend or Hibernate), it does so through "Power Management". Read `man pm-action` which says, in part:

```
   /etc/pm/sleep.d, /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d
       Programs in these directories (called hooks) are combined and
       executed in C sort order before suspend and hibernate with as
       argument 'suspend' or 'hibernate'. Afterwards they are called in
       reverse order with argument 'resume' and 'thaw' respectively. If
       both directories contain a similar named file, the one in
       /etc/pm/sleep.d will get preference. It is possible to disable a
       hook in the distribution directory by putting a non-executable file
       in /etc/pm/sleep.d, or by adding it to the HOOK_BLACKLIST
       configuration variable.
```

You can put an executable copy of your script (ready to handle the parameter "suspend", "hibernate", "resume" or "thaw") in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`